# Sitecore 8, Security editor, Not able to see access rights for the role "Everyone"

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I want to check what rights the default role "Everyone" has on the **Home** item. In the security editor, I chose the account "Everyone" and clicked on Access Viewer, but I am getting the error, "Account domain not found".

[image]

The deails of the error:

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Account domain not found.

Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: Account domain not found.]
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.Shell.AccessViewer.Execute(CommandContext context) +741
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Dispatcher.Dispatch(Message message, CommandContext context) +63
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Security.SecurityEditor.SecurityEditorForm.HandleMessage(Message message) +724
   Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.MessageCommand.Execute(CommandContext context) +441
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.Dispatch(String command) +143
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.RaiseEvent() +101
   Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +553
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +88
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4775
```

I have no idea what is causing the above mentioned exception.

Comment: Did you try opening the `Access Viewer` and then selecting the `Everyone` role? This looks like an error in the code that switches the applications

Comment: Yes, from this way its working. But as soon as I click on "Security Editor" I get the same error again.

Comment: I get the same error also. Seems like a Sitecore bug.